# Add Page Tab dialog not working

Tags: facebook, tabs

I was always using the direct Add to Page Tab URL like this:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=238557109577754&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com

And today that URL gives me "**Sorry, something went wrong.**". Did something changed on Facebook side? Or is it a temporary bug?

Note that I have tried other redirect_uri params, such as the URL of the location where the app is hosted. It does always result in the same error.

**Edit:** It's a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304168516342380

You can use Graph API Explorer to add your page tab over API as a workaround. See the link above for details.

Comment: I get the same thing. I even tried to install older apps(did the install before; worked, no settings changed since) on a dummy page and the result is the same: "something went wrong"...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304168516342380

Comment: Yep it's the bug. There is a workaround you can use now to add your pages with Graph API and API Explorer (description available in that link above). I did and that worked!

Answer (score 9):

It seems that Facebook has made another change and has not informed anyone. Below is a new link that appears to work. Just replace APP-ID with your application ID.

https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key={APP-ID}&pages=1

Comment: you saved my day. i spent a whole day do nothing but wait them fix the error message.. their document not reliable.

Comment: This does sort of work, but it asks for a Canvas Callback URL, which isn't always required for simple tabs. The Graph API Explorer method works 100%.

Comment: That's an old, deprecated endpoint, apart from the fact there was a bug affecting the normal way to add page tabs, i wouldn't recommend use of that

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages=1

replace APP_ID with your application id